# Making a larger string do as the smaller string (zoom in or zoom out) [CSS]

Tags: html, css, string

I am having an issue where my larger string remains underneath the image when I zoom out but the smaller strings ("FIRST & SECOND") are going to the side of the image. I need help making a larger string act like the smaller ones, so their movement is relevant. The larger string stays at the bottom and doesn't move unlike the other two strings.

```
h3 {
  color: #323a45;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #2f7bbd;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2ou3xt1a/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the following CSS:

```css
h3 {
  color: #323a45;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #2f7bbd;
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```